# In vim, why does c_ behave as if cc?

Tags: vim

As the title.

Since `_` is the movement to the first non-whitespace character in the line, and `c + movement` generally means to change (aka delete + go into insert mode) the buffer from the cursor to the movement, why does this not work? It seems to delete the entire line, instead of from the cursor to the beginning of line (aka `cc` or `C`). Is there an alternative for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue in vim. See https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2189#issuecomment-334441965:

> `_` is a linewise movement (I guess because of VI compatibility). All commands (like `d` or `c`) that are combined with a linewise movement
>   affect whole lines. You can make the movement (in combination with a
>   command) characterwise by prefixing it with `v`. So `cv_` and `dv_` should
>   do what you want.

Comment: Perfect! Seems to work great, cv_ and dv_. However, yv_ doesn't work tho. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Because `_` is defined as an up/down motion. From `:help up-down-motions`:

```
_  <underscore>     [count] - 1 lines downward, on the first non-blank
                    character |linewise|.
```

It just defines the position where the cursor will end up once the up/down motion is finished. Thus, `c_` operates on lines, just like `cj` does.

Answer (score 1):

[Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47986556/6476951) give's the reason why `c_` doesn't work.

---

Answering the second part of your question

> Is there an alternative for this?

Yes, there is. Use `c^`!

Check out `:help left-right-motions` and you'll find:

```
^                   To the first non-blank character of the line.
                    exclusive motion.
```